# How to use docker-ce under ubuntu on Digital Ocean?

Tags: docker, lamp

Using docker-ce for lamp apps I got url like http://127.0.0.1:8084/ and it works under my local ubuntu 18. I need to install docker-ce under my ubuntu 16 on Digital Ocean with hosting which I created in https://my.freenom.com

Are there some addons/instructions how can I do it ?

Searching in net I found this https://github.com/nginx-proxy/nginx-proxy extention, but my docker apps are based on apache. Are there something like that, but for apache?

Thanks!

...

Comment: I think you may be a bit confused about how docker works. You probably don't need a proxy of any sort. You can publish ports from your containers so that they will be accessible on your virtual host's ip address.

Comment: Can you give some example, please or ref to related description?